# How can I search for a hex string in oracle?

Tags: oracle, query, encoding, regular-expression, string-searching

There's a database record that is incorrect. The name field displays like this in a browser ( this is incorrect ):

```
Thcˇodore
```

And when I look at the record via SQL results, I see:

```
Thc\xCB\x87odore
```

I'm trying to search for other records that might be affected, so I would like to query the `name` field for any value "`LIKE`" `\xCB\x87`

I've tried using `HEXTORAW` and many other combinations including:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(NAME, \'\xCC\x88\' )

REGEXP_LIKE(NAME, \'[\xCC\x88]\' )

NAME like '%' || HEXTORAW(\'CC88\') || '%'

NAME LIKE ‘%’ || X’CC’ || X’88’ ||’%’

NAME like \'%\' || \'\x88\' || \'%\'
```

Can't seem to get any of them to work, and I can't find any other examples or documentation online. Maybe I've been googling for the wrong things but this is what I've tried to google:

1. oracle escape hexadecimal
2. oracle hex to ascii
3. oracle like hexadecimal query
4. oracle pcre Hexadecimeal select
5. oracle query binary character
6. oracle REGEXP_LIKE hexadecimal
7. oracle select \x0A
8. oracle select escape character hex
9. oracle select hex codes
10. oracle select like \x0a
11. oracle select REGEXP_LIKE \x0A
12. oracle select X 0A

#### How can I search for `\xCB\x87` with Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SQL> create table t1(c1 varchar2(20 char));

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 values ('Thcˇodore');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from t1;

C1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Thcˇodore

SQL> select rawtohex(c1) from t1;

RAWTOHEX(C1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
546863CB876F646F7265

SQL> select c1 from t1 where rawtohex(c1) like '%CB87%';

C1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Thcˇodore

SQL>
```